# Looking for help in drawing diagrams to explain graphically NASA Horizons output

Tags: nasa, ephemeris, horizons, javascript

I searched a lot for a javascript library or a REST API to access full functionalities of powerful [NASA Horizons tool](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi), but with no luck, so I am trying to [write my own interface](http://win98.altervista.org/space/exploration/NHUGUI.html), to replace the very simple one provided by NASA, which only allows setting 6 parameters [out of 40](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?horizons_doc).

My page does not perform any check on input: all you write is sent as-is to Horizons server, but I tried at least to take into account dependencies of some parameters from others, as per [Horizons manual](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?horizons_doc).

Page is not yet complete, but at least now it is possible to get the results in the same window of the query, and also to get with just one click:

- full list of available spacecrafts
- full list of available solar system bodies
- full list of available earth observatories
- full list of available [output quantities](http://win98.altervista.org/space/exploration/quantities.html), with full description of each one

About this last point, I am looking for some help: some of these quantities are quite complex, and I would like to add a picture explaining each one of them; I found some pictures on wikipedia, but was not able to find pictures for many others, so some help in drawing from scratch such pictures would be appreciated.

I prepared three images, now it's "just" a matter of associating quantities numbers to angle/segments in the images...

My page: http://win98.altervista.org/space/exploration/NHUGUI.html

Output quantities: http://win98.altervista.org/space/exploration/quantities.html

[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

Comment: Horizons data doesn't support API access, as an FYI.

Comment: I wrote my own "API", if you want to call it like that, which turns user's selection into proper URL request and returns a structured javascript object.

Comment: apart from this, question is not "where can I find an API?" but "is anybody able to help me drawing some images?"

Comment: I understand. I mean that you "using it as an API" is also frowned upon by NASA and you may or may not be blocked at any given time. No need for the sarcasm, it won't get you answers. Apart from this, if the question isn't about the **Horizons data** and is solely about **Programming in JavaScript** then, imo, it isn't on topic here at all and should be migrated to a programming SE.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I didn't read any sarcasm in jumpjack's comment, for what it's worth. Also, this is not a programming question, but a question about creating diagrams related to solar-system bodies using information provided by a NASA tool. The information about the program is peripheral.

Comment: any suggestion where else I could find experts about astrometry?

Comment: You might lookup the Wikipedia articles on each term used by HORIZONS to see if you can find imagery there. Google Images would be another good starting point. I'm not convinced all HORIZONS quantities can be represented graphically, but I'm sure many of them can be.

Comment: wikipedia is useful for all but images :-(

Comment: Found a good & official source, will try to extract some images:  https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/Tutorials/pdf/individual_docs/17_frames_and_coordinate_systems.pdf

Comment: After studying a lot I ended up with several explanatory images. Any comment about their correctness would be appreciated: http://win98.altervista.org/space/exploration/quantities.html